# java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.createStatement()" because "connection" is null

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>

<%

Connection connection=null;
    try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/social_network","root","Apsa@123");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }       

%>
```

I am getting the exception below

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
> "java.sql.Connection.createStatement()" because "connection" is null

Comment: You most likely have an exception printed to System.out you need to attend to.

Comment: Check your service like ( XAMPP,etc)  is running or not, before running the code.

Comment: Your connection is obviously null. Probably because of exception. You need either find out, what System.out.println(e); prints, or use logger to log exception. Also if all of that is hard for you, you could just write details of Exception to a file manually in catch block.

Comment: Do not catch exceptions and continue on as if nothing happened.